# Canvas is not redrawn when i switch fragments?

Tags: android, canvas, android-fragments

I have 4 `Fragments` , one navigation Fragment with 3 buttons and 3 canvas Fragments. Since i need to calculate size of the `layout` in my `Fragment` i used `onfocuschangedlistener` to draw on the `canvas`.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) 
    {
            //calculate width and height of available space 
            //instansiate view object 
            layout.removeAllViews();
            layout.addView(view object);
    }
});
```

This works fine when the app is loaded for the first time, and i load view by default, but after that once i start switching between fragments by means of the Navigation fragment , the view is never redrawn. I found that `onglobalfocuschange`  is never called again even if i load another `Fragment`. How can i  accomplish this. Appreciate any suggestions.

Here is my View class which draws a bargraph. Right now i am just using constant values for testing.

```
public class bargraphClass extends View
    {
        int startX,startY,stopX,stopY;
        int leftSp,bottomSp;
        RectF fillRect;
        float hrs;
        float ppm;
        Paint rectBrush=new Paint();
        int g1,g2,g3,g4;
        public bargraphClass(Context context,int wt,int ht) 
        {
            super(context);
            leftSp=wt/5;
            bottomSp=ht/20;
            startX=leftSp;
            startY=0;
            stopX=wt;
            stopY=ht-bottomSp;
            fillRect=new RectF();
            g1=5*60;
            g2=4*60;
            g3=8*60;
            g4=6*60;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas c) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int _wt,gap,temp;       
            super.onDraw(c);
            drawAxis(c);
            ppm=(float)(stopY-startY)/(24*60);
            _wt=stopX-startX;
            gap=_wt/9;

            temp=(int) (g1*ppm);
            fillRect.set(startX+gap, stopY-temp, startX+(gap*2), stopY);            
            rectBrush.setColor(Color.RED);
            rectBrush.setAntiAlias(true);
            rectBrush.setAlpha(128);
            c.drawRect(fillRect,rectBrush);

            temp=(int) (g2*ppm);
            fillRect.set(startX+(gap*3), stopY-temp, startX+(gap*4), stopY);            
            rectBrush.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            rectBrush.setAntiAlias(true);
            rectBrush.setAlpha(128);
            c.drawRect(fillRect,rectBrush);

            temp=(int) (g3*ppm);
            fillRect.set(startX+(gap*5), stopY-temp, startX+(gap*6), stopY);            
            rectBrush.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            rectBrush.setAntiAlias(true);
            rectBrush.setAlpha(128);
            c.drawRect(fillRect,rectBrush);

            temp=(int) (g4*ppm);
            fillRect.set(startX+(gap*7), stopY-temp, startX+(gap*8), stopY);            
            rectBrush.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            rectBrush.setAntiAlias(true);
            rectBrush.setAlpha(128);
            c.drawRect(fillRect,rectBrush);

        }

        private void setScaleValues()
        {
            ppm=stopY/(24*60);
        }

        private void drawAxis(Canvas c)
        {
            int sp;
            String str;
            Paint p=new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            p.setStrokeWidth(2);
            p.setAntiAlias(true);

            c.drawLine(startX,startY,startX,stopY, p);
            c.drawLine(startX, stopY, stopX, stopY, p);

            sp=(stopY-startY)/12;
            for(int i=1;i<12;i++)
            {
                str=String.valueOf(i*2)+" hrs";
                c.drawText(str, 0, ht-(i*sp)-bottomSp,p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `SurfaceView` in the fragments ?

Comment: @User117 Not sure what that means, just started on graphics.I have a view class in which i draw a graph and then add it to the layout.

Comment: @User117 I have added my View class if thats any help.